# Rectangle Area and Perimeter

Tags: java

I have an assignment that I am having trouble figuring out.

---

Write an application (Rectangle.java) that asks the user to enter the length and the width of a rectangle (both are positive double-precision floating-point numbers), and prints the area and perimeter of the rectangle. When the user enters 7.9 and 4.5, the output of your program should look exactly like the following:

```
Enter the length and the width of a rectangle: 7.9 4.5
The area of the rectangle is 35.55.
The perimeter of the rectangle is 24.80.
```

---

The part I am having trouble with is bringing the output of the perimeter of the rectangle out to two decimal places including the "0."  I have been trying to figure it out for so long.  I know there must be a simple efficient way to do this or it would not be assigned to us as our second Java homework assignment.  If it is to format it as %2d i do not know how to apply that to what i have.  I REALLY appreciate your help!

Here is what i have so far:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Rectangle {
public static void main(String[] args) {
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Enter the length and the width of a rectangle: ");
double length = input.nextDouble();
double width = input.nextDouble();
double area = (length * width);
double perimeter = (length * 2 + width * 2);
System.out.println("The area of the rectangle is " + (int)(area * 100) / 100.0 + ".");
System.out.println("The perimeter of the rectangle is " + (int)(perimeter * 100) / 100.0 + ".");
}
}
```

My Output:

```
Enter the length and the width of a rectangle: 7.9 4.5
The area of the rectangle is 35.55.
The perimeter of the rectangle is 24.8.
```

Comment: The format string syntax is explained at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax and one way to use it is explained at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html#format(java.lang.String, java.lang.Object...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read the documentation about [`String.format()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29) and the [format string syntax](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax). This will help you find the right format string to output the numbers as required.

Basically you'd have to have the last two lines of code to:

```
System.out.println("The area of the rectangle is " + String.format("%.2f", area) + ".");
System.out.println("The perimeter of the rectangle is " + String.format("%.2f", perimeter) + ".");
```

Comment: If you're using `"%.2f"`, you don't need to mess about with the whole `* 100`, cast to `int` then divide by `100.0` business.

Comment: Thank y'all so much!!  The string was where I had been messing it up :)

Comment: The equivalent of *Thank you* on StackOverflow is to upvote/accept the answer that helped you :-)

Comment: Oh! I just tried to and it said I must have a reputation of 15 first. I will upvote as soon as I get 15 points!

Answer (score 1):

You need `%.2f` in `format`:

```
System.out.printf("The perimeter of the rectangle is %.2f", 24.8);
```

The `24.8` is just for test, you may replace it with the correct expresion.